# Port forwarding is not working after re-installation of docker

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

#### Description

I am running a container with the nginx docker image using `docker compose`.
I am using custom bridge network with port forwarding and the container is running fine. I am able to access the forwarded port from the host machine.

The problem is coming after I reinstall the docker. The container is coming up but I am unable to access the service with the forwarded port.

#### Reproduce

1. Install docker from here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
2. Start docker compose

   - sudo docker compose -f nginx.yml up -d
   - Do telnet (telnet <host_ip> 7777)
   - This works fine
3. Do the reinstall (clean and install)

   - bash docker_install.sh
4. Start docker compose again

   - sudo docker compose -f nginx.yml up -d
   - Do telnet (telnet <host_ip> 7777)
   - This fails with the error `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`

Below is the compose yml file

```
# nginx.yml

version: '3.3'
name: nginx
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 7777:80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx_network
networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.4.0.0/16
```

Below is the script to clean and install the docker

```
# docker_install.sh

function install_root_docker() {
    # Add Docker's official GPG key:
    sudo apt-get update -y
    sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg -y
    sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
    sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

    # Add the repository to Apt sources:
    echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
    sudo apt-get update -y
    sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin -y

    sudo systemctl enable docker.service

    sudo systemctl start docker.service
    sudo systemctl is-active docker.service
}

function clean_root_docker() {
    sudo systemctl stop docker.service docker.socket
    sudo apt-get purge -y containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras pigz slirp4netns
    sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras pigz slirp4netns
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
    sudo rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/docker
    sudo groupdel docker
    sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
    sudo rm -rf ~/.docker
    sudo apt -y autoremove
}

clean_root_docker
install_root_docker
```